# AttributeError: 'Game' object has no attribute 'run'

Tags: python

I'm a beginner for Py game and this if my first problem. The full error is

I have tried many other website too but cannot find the answer related this this specific code, Someone told that i should place the game.run under the game class but even that didn't work

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Coding\Python stuff\Xenomorph Slayer\main.py", line 39, in <module>
    game.run()
    ^^^^^^^^AttributeError: 'Game' object has no attribute 'run
```

```
import pygame as pg
import sys
from settings import *

class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        pg.init
        self.screen = pg.display.set_mode(RES)
        self.clock = pg.time.Clock()

        def new_game(self):
            pass

        def update(self):
            pg.display.flip()
            self.clock.tick(FPS)
            pg.display.set_caption(f'{self.clock.get_fps() :.1f}')
        
        def check_event(self):
            for event in pg.evernt.get():
                if event == pg.QUIT or (event.type == pg.KEYDOWN and event.key == pg.K_ESCAPE):
                    pg.quit()
                    sys.exit()
            

            def draw(self):
                self.screen.fill('black')

            def run(seld):
                while True:
                    self.check_event()
                    self.update()
                    self.draw()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    game = Game()
    game.run()
```

Comment: Did you copy the indentation accurately? If so, you have defined `run()` inside the defintion of `check_event`. Just fix the indentation and your problem should be solved.

Comment: Both `run()` and `draw()` methods are indented to be within the scope of `check_event()`. You need to de-indent them and also fix the typo `run(seld)` → `run(self)`.

Answer (score 0):

try to align all the def in same position, until the name of def change color (depends on IDE)

```
class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        pg.init
        self.screen = pg.display.set_mode(RES)
        self.clock = pg.time.Clock()

    def new_game(self):
            pass

    def update(self):
            pg.display.flip()
            self.clock.tick(FPS)
            pg.display.set_caption(f'{self.clock.get_fps() :.1f}')
        
    def check_event(self):
            for event in pg.evernt.get():
                if event == pg.QUIT or (event.type == pg.KEYDOWN and event.key == pg.K_ESCAPE):
                    pg.quit()
                    sys.exit()
            

     def draw(self):
                self.screen.fill('black')

     def run(seld):
                while True:
                    self.check_event()
                    self.update()
                    self.draw()
```

Comment: Im still getting the same error i have tried your code

Comment: def run(seld): changes to def run(self):